# Ebay Shopping API

Tags: ebay-api

Hi All! I want to get public user information about seller in ebay, for this I use ebay [shopping API](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetUserProfile.html#Samples):

```
http://open.api.sandbox.ebay.com/shopping?
   callname=GetUserProfile&
   responseencoding=XML&
   appid=YourAppId&
   siteid=0&
   UserID=TESTUSER_magicalbookseller&
   version=773
```

In the appid I put my appid. For the UserId=TESTUSER_magicalbookseller it works, but when I try another user ids selected for random from ebay, it does not work. Is there any problem and how can I get user profile?

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you use the sandbox you have to use the sandbox userids not the ones from the live site, for example you could use: **TESTUSER_schwarz**.

**Sidenote for `GetUser`-Call from the trading API:** You can only retrieve detailed user information for users you have a relation to, for example a transaction (user has bought stuff from your account). Also if you had a relation to a user, there is a certain time limit in which the informaton is available

Comment: where I can get sanbox userids or is there any other way of getting userids? Also your sidenote is for trading API, but I use shopping API

Comment: Easily go to http://sandbox.ebay.com/ and search for auctions, there you should be able to see the userids.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue in your API call and it should work fine

In EBay sandbox mode, we dont expect all API call working; you can test it with live account endpoint

I have tested with live account Appid. Its working fine